# Is it possible to sort an Acumatica report by a calculated field (formula)?

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb, report-designer

I'm trying to sort by the result of the division of two of the columns of the report.
I've tried to add the formula to the **sorting and grouping** section of the report but I have not been able to make it work

[image]

does anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report engine fetch data by generating a SQL query from the report schema builder configuration. I believe the fields declared in the OrderBy clause needs to be bound (must exist in database) because of that design choice.

Note that the generated request is available from the `Tools->Trace Window` when executing the report:
[image]